# problem with php artisan migrate while deploying laravel app to heroku

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, heroku

I was deploying my laravel app to heroku. Everything was going fine, but when I had to migrate my database (which is on phpmyadmin) I am getting the following error on executing the command php artisan migrate.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema =
   database_lms and table_name = migrations)



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I have a database called database_lms within which I have the migrations table.
This is my .env file

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=database_lms
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=
```

and here is my config/database.php file containing the mysql parameters

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_lms'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

I have tried changing DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1, but this also isn't working.
I have also run php artisan config:cache, and then run php artisan migrate but have got the same error. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have the same DB created on Heroku?

Comment: Do I need to create the DB on Heroku before I can proceed?

Comment: Try this  php artisan migrate --env=production

Comment: You have to create the DB first

Comment: I have the DB created on phpmyadmin, do I need to create it on heroku as well?

Comment: "I have the DB created on phpmyadmin" You mean in your localhost or in the server?

Comment: i mean on my localhost

Comment: Create DB in server. Change credentials in the .env file and try 'php artisan migrate' or 'php artisan migrate --env=production'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183118/discussion-between-siddharth-sampath-and-sreekanth-mk).